# Strange results when using ForLoop to read CSV and add data to list

Tags: python-3.x

I have some code that reads data in a csv file and stores it in a list. Later in the program I edit this list and add new data to it.

```
fileData = []
with open('translation list.csv', 'r') as rFile:
    fileReader = csv.reader(rFile)

    for row in fileReader:
    fileData.append(row)
```

The last line of this code seems to be causing problems.

Now every line that gets read is wrapped in `[ ]` and I can't figure out why. So I end up with a csv that looks like this:

> [[[list item 4]]]
>
> [[list item 3]]
>
> [list item 2]
>
> list item 1

Comment: What does "it didn't like this line" mean? Did you get an error? If so, what error? How does this code relate to your tkinter code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `+=` with lists `a` and `b` (`a += b`), it will add all individual items from `b` to the end of `a`. When you use `a.append(b)`, it adds the entire list `b` to the end of `a`. Observe:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [3]: a.append(b)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, ['a', 'b', 'c']]
```

Compared to:

```
In [1]: a = [1, 2, 3]

In [2]: b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [3]: a += b

In [4]: a
Out[4]: [1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

Each `row` in `for row in fileReader` is a list itself, so when you append that list to an existing list, you get a list of lists, rather than single flat list of items in each list.